# TIRF mycroscopy with intermediate layer of different refraction index

Tags: optics, refraction, microscopy

I`m currently experimenting with through the lens TIRF microscopy in which an additional layer is used between the glass and the sample. This 10-30 μm layer has a higher refraction index than my sample (cells) but lower than glass. Similar to panel B in the figure.

[image: TIRF]

In regular TIRF (case A), the parallel rays reach the surface of the sample at the center of the objective field of view. But it seems that when the additional layer is added the ray does not reach the sample at the center of the field of view. This is similar to what I have observed, as soon as I start reaching the angles to go in to TIR the illumination beam seems to drift from the center of my sample on to the periphery, until the point I can't it goes out the field of view.

What is the reason for this? And how can it be fixed?

The figure is from [this paper](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0023807#pone.0023807-Iwadate2)

You can find a similar example in this [other paper](https://www.future-science.com/doi/full/10.2144/000112752)

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting total internal reflection at the interface between the silicone gel and the cover glass.  Some possible solutions:  1) find a lower refractive index cover glass and oil; 2) find a higher refractive index substitute for the silicone gel.

You didn't specify the thickness of the silicone gel layer.  It might be acting as an antireflection coating since it has a somewhat intermediate refractive index between the 1.52 of your cover glass and the 1.33 of your sample.  You could try making that layer thicker.

If the issue is simply that the illumination is offset laterally when you add the  silicone gel, you might be able to bring it back to the right location by using a thinner cover glass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I'm not getting TIRF in the intermediate layer because the light still reaches the cells. The thickness is 10-30 μm. I'll try changing the cover glass thickness.

Answer (score 0):

TIRF objectives often have adjustment collars. These are precisely for compensating slightly different coverglass thicknesses. Adding 10-30um of silicone gel is nearly identical in result to using a 0.18-0.20mm coverglass which can be corrected by adjusting the collar.